# можно ли опрелелить viewport в пределах медиа-запроса

Tags: html, css, media-queries, responsive

Получил задание, адаптировать старенький сайт сделанный на CMS Diafan:
[artmaster.com.ua](http://artmaster.com.ua).

Через '@media' полностью подогнал его под максимальную ширину 320px. При этом структура контента сильно меняется и стили до 320px и после 320px несовместимы.

Минимальная ширина декстопного контента 760px, меньше он не ужимается так как установлен 'min-width'. При этом минимальное разрешение при котором весь контент отображается правильно 800px - если уменьшать, он просто прячется за правой гранью окна.

Вопрос: Можно ли используя мета-тег 'viewport' сделать так, чтобы сайт подстраивался под разрешение девайса, и при этом весь контент отображался !И!
данное действие происходило только когда максимальная ширина девайса находится между 320px и 800px.

P.S.:Если нет, то подскажите, пожалуйста, какое решение стоит применить в данном случае.

Comment: а почему не использовать те же @media для ширины от 320 до 800 ? да, займет время выстилизировать все элементы под разные экраны.

Comment: И если задание адаптировать под все устройства(в смысле телефоны, планшеты и т.д.) то лучше использовать более принятые медиа запросы: `max-width: 767`, `min-width: 768 max: 991`, `min:992 max: 1199`, `min:1200`. А то к примеру на 6 айфоне ваш сайт уже плохо выглядит.

Comment: Спасибо, за ваш ответ) да, это решение я и применяю, но если бы был способ просто задать вьюпорт в пределах проблемного разрешения, то я бы хотел его попробовать.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте тогда:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) 
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px)
@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px)
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px)
```

Последний если надо конечно)

Если оставить просто до 320px то на большинстве устройств при *landscape* будет выглядеть плохо. В хроме в **developer tools** есть неплохое средство тестирования вида на мобильных устройствах. Можете проверять как будет приблизительно выглядеть на разных телефонах / планшетах

Answer (score 1):

Для меня сработало следующее решение: я прописал скрипт прямо под мета-тегом 'viewport', а самому тегу дал одноименный id. Скрипт менял контент тега когда ширина экрана находилась в диапазоне 320-800px.

```
<meta name="viewport" id="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    setViewPort();
       function setViewPort() {
          if (screen.width > 320 && screen.width < 800) {
          document.getElementById("viewport").removeAttribute("content");
          document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, maximum-scale=0.5");
    } else {
        document.getElementById("viewport").removeAttribute("content");
        document.getElementById("viewport").setAttribute("content", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1");
    }
}

</script>
```

В окончательном варианте, под свой конкретный случай я немного упростил его, но суть осталось той же.